# How to convert image byte array into a bitmap after altering with the byte array

Tags: java, android, arrays, bitmap, steganography

I am trying to implement Steganography in Android and I have implemented the code to encode the image bit by bit.

```
private Bitmap add_text(Bitmap image, String text)
{
    //convert all items to byte arrays: image, message, message length
    byte img[]  = get_byte_data(image);
    byte msg[] = text.getBytes();
    byte len[]   = bit_conversion(msg.length);
    displaybit(img, "Start");

    try
    {
        encode_text(img, len,  0); //0 first positiong
        encode_text(img, msg, 32); //4 bytes of space for length: 4bytes*8bit = 32 bits

        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}

private byte[] get_byte_data(Bitmap image)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

    return stream.toByteArray();
}

private byte[] bit_conversion(int i)
{
    //originally integers (ints) cast into bytes
    //byte byte7 = (byte)((i & 0xFF00000000000000L) >>> 56);
    //byte byte6 = (byte)((i & 0x00FF000000000000L) >>> 48);
    //byte byte5 = (byte)((i & 0x0000FF0000000000L) >>> 40);
    //byte byte4 = (byte)((i & 0x000000FF00000000L) >>> 32);

    //only using 4 bytes
    byte byte3 = (byte)((i & 0xFF000000) >>> 24); //0
    byte byte2 = (byte)((i & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16); //0
    byte byte1 = (byte)((i & 0x0000FF00) >>> 8 ); //0
    byte byte0 = (byte)((i & 0x000000FF)       );
    //{0,0,0,byte0} is equivalent, since all shifts >=8 will be 0
    return(new byte[]{byte3,byte2,byte1,byte0});
}

private byte[] encode_text(byte[] image, byte[] addition, int offset)
{
    //check that the data + offset will fit in the image
    if(addition.length + offset > image.length)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File not long enough!");
    }
    //loop through each addition byte
    for(int i=0; i<addition.length; ++i)
    {
        //loop through the 8 bits of each byte
        int add = addition[i]; //0
        for(int bit=7; bit>=0; --bit, ++offset) //ensure the new offset value carries on through both loops
        {
            //assign an integer to b, shifted by bit spaces AND 1
            //a single bit of the current byte
            int b = (add >>> bit) & 1;
            //assign the bit by taking: [(previous byte value) AND 0xfe] OR bit to add
            //changes the last bit of the byte in the image to be the bit of addition
            image[offset] = (byte)((image[offset] & 0xFE) | b );
        }
    }
    return image;
}
```

But I am not able to form a bitmap after encoding the data into the image.

I have implemented the same algorithm in java and it works fine:

```
private BufferedImage add_text(BufferedImage image, String text)
{
    //convert all items to byte arrays: image, message, message length
    byte img[]  = get_byte_data(image);
    byte msg[] = text.getBytes();
    byte len[]   = bit_conversion(msg.length);
    try
    {
        encode_text(img, len,  0); //0 first positiong
        encode_text(img, msg, 32); //4 bytes of space for length: 4bytes*8bit = 32 bits
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, 
"Target File cannot hold message!", "Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
    return image;
}
```

So could some one please help me figure out why the byte array is invalid in the case of android.

Comment: Without knowing what `get_byte_data()` does, what `bit_conversion()` does, or what `encode_text()` does, it is impossible to help you. Bear in mind that the `byte[]` that you pass to `decodeByteArray()` needs to be in a recognized and supported image format (e.g., PNG, JPEG, WebP).

Comment: Ok I'll put the code

Answer (score 1):

You start with a `byte[]` of JPEG data. You then modify that data, changing bits semi-randomly, without regard to the JPEG data format. You then attempt to decode the modified `byte[]`. Not surprisingly, `BitmapFactory` cannot decode it, as it is no longer a valid image format.

My best guess is that you think that the `byte[]` is raw pixels in ARGB format.

If that is the case, then use methods like `getPixel()` and `setPixel()` on `Bitmap` to modify the pixels, and skip the bitmap encoding and decoding steps.

Comment: Actually, I need to alter the bytes so is there any way to alter the bytes without corrupting them. As in case of Java which I have mentioned above the same algorithm is giving me the correct output.

Comment: @SatyamRai: "I need to alter the bytes" -- why? "so is there any way to alter the bytes without corrupting them" -- make sure you wind up with a valid JPEG when you are done. I do not know how you intend to do that. "As in case of Java which I have mentioned above the same algorithm is giving me the correct output" -- `BufferedImage` is not a JPEG.

Comment: Since I am implementing steganography so I want to encode the message in every byte of the image bit by bit. So is there any alternative for BufferedImage in Android other than Bitmap.

Comment: @SatyamRai: "Since I am implementing steganography so I want to encode the message in every byte of the image bit by bit" -- adjust your algorithm to encode the message on a pixel-by-pixel basis. Then, save the image as a PNG, as otherwise your encoded data will be lost if you encode to a JPEG. Or, use the NDK and `libjpeg` to work with JPEG images directly, if you are sure that you want JPEG output. There are existing open source steganography code samples for Android; perhaps look to those for ideas.

Comment: @SatyamRai This is the answer you're looking for. You may not like it, but it's the reality. Steganography that modifies directly the bytes of the image file works on formats like bmp, where the bytes represent the raw data. That is absolutely not the case for compressed formats. The advice of saving the modified image to a lossless format if you want to modify the pixels themselves is equally important.

Comment: Thank you for your help I'll try out other ways as you guys suggested. Please help me if I am stuck at some point

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to figure it out, as mentioned above in the comment the solution was solving it pixel by pixel. So I took a pixel and put the data in its rgb value bit by bit. So this is the code:

```
private Bitmap add_text(Bitmap image, String text, File tempFile) {
    //convert all items to byte arrays: image, message, message length
    byte msg[] = text.getBytes();
    byte len[] = bit_conversion(msg.length);

    try {

        return encodeTextRGB(image, len, msg, tempFile);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return image;
}

private byte[] bit_conversion(int i) {
    //originally integers (ints) cast into bytes
    //byte byte7 = (byte)((i & 0xFF00000000000000L) >>> 56);
    //byte byte6 = (byte)((i & 0x00FF000000000000L) >>> 48);
    //byte byte5 = (byte)((i & 0x0000FF0000000000L) >>> 40);
    //byte byte4 = (byte)((i & 0x000000FF00000000L) >>> 32);

    //only using 4 bytes
    byte byte3 = (byte) ((i & 0xFF000000) >>> 24); //0
    byte byte2 = (byte) ((i & 0x00FF0000) >>> 16); //0
    byte byte1 = (byte) ((i & 0x0000FF00) >>> 8); //0
    byte byte0 = (byte) ((i & 0x000000FF));
    //{0,0,0,byte0} is equivalent, since all shifts >=8 will be 0
    return (new byte[]{byte3, byte2, byte1, byte0});
}

public Bitmap encodeTextRGB(Bitmap buffer, byte[] len, byte[] data, File tempFile) {

    pixelRow = 0;
    pixelCol = 0;

    byte[] overhead = len;

    int bitCount = 0;
    int iteration = 0;

    while (iteration++ < 2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < overhead.length; i++) {
            byte currentByte = overhead[i];
            System.out.println("add: " + currentByte);
            for (int j = 7; j >= 0; j--) {
                int bit = (currentByte & (0x1 << j)) >> j;
                bit = bit & 0x1;
                System.out.println("Bit: " + bit);
                if (bitCount % 3 == 0) {
                    int red;
                    if (bit == 0) {
                        red = Color.red(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)) & 0xFE;
                    } else {
                        red = Color.red(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)) | 0x1;
                    }
                    buffer.setPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow, Color.argb(
                            Color.alpha(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)), red,
                            Color.green(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)),
                            Color.blue(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow))));
                } else if (bitCount % 3 == 1) {
                    int blue;
                    if (bit == 0) {
                        blue = Color.blue(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)) & 0xFE;
                    } else {
                        blue = Color.blue(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)) | 0x1;
                    }
                    buffer.setPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow, Color.argb(
                            Color.alpha(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)),
                            Color.red(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)),
                            Color.green(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)), blue));
                } else {
                    int green;
                    if (bit == 0) {
                        green = Color.green(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)) & 0xFE;
                    } else {
                        green = Color.green(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)) | 0x1;
                    }
                    buffer.setPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow, Color.argb(
                            Color.alpha(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)),
                            Color.red(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow)), green,
                            Color.blue(buffer.getPixel(pixelCol, pixelRow))));
                    incrementPixel(buffer.getWidth());
                }
                bitCount++;
            }
        }

        overhead = data;
    }
    FileOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
        buffer.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    incrementPixel(buffer.getWidth());
    return buffer;
}
```